# How do I get Pod IP with dns?

Tags: kubernetes

There is Pod with Centos. I want to get Pod IP by DNS. But there was an error.

```
[root@namenode /]# nslookup namenode.space.default.svc.cluster.local
Server:         10.96.0.10
Address:        10.96.0.10#53
** server can't find namenode.space.default.svc.cluster.local: NXDOMAIN

[root@namenode /]# nslookup namenode
Server:         10.96.0.10
Address:        10.96.0.10#53

Name:   namenode.default.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.107.117.123
```

This is my yaml file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
 name: test-con
 labels:
  app: test
spec:
 hostname: namenode
 subdomain: space
 containers:
 - name: test-con
   image: 192.168.50.130:5000/test
   command: [ "/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: namenode
spec:
  selector:
    name: test
  ports:
   -  name: "ssh"
      port: 22
      targetPort: 22
  type: NodePort
```

namespace is default. How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First take a look into https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#pod-s-hostname-and-subdomain-fields.

According to this tutorial you have to change some parts:

- update `spec.selector` to `app: test` in your service.
- service name has to be equal with the `spec.subdomain`.
- service has to be `headless` (`spec.clusterIP` set to `None`)

After everything is ready, try `$ namenode.space.default.svc.cluster.local`.

Answer (score 1):

When you nslookup the normal service name `nslookup namenode` it returns the clusterIP which is assigned to it. Whenever any request comes to that services, using kube-proxy it automatically discover the pod and send it to that pod. Hence, kube-dns doesn't know th podIP in advance, it just knows clusterIP and rest responsibility is of kube-proxy to find the pod.

To do pod discovery your own way, you need to use the headless service, which returns all the Pod IP  attached to that service. However, the use case of headless service is in case of you have statefulset and each replica has its own PV, PVC. To define a headless service you need to provide `clusterIP: None` in the service definition. Please look at the my answer related to headless service

[Kubernetes service architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53358976/kubernetes-service-architecture/53359338#53359338)

According to your question if you just need Pod IP inside the pod, then you can use the environment variable to do it for you. Add the config block below to your pod definition:

```
env:
- name: MY_POD_NAME
  valueFrom:
    fieldRef:
      fieldPath: metadata.name
- name: MY_POD_NAMESPACE
  valueFrom:
    fieldRef:
      fieldPath: metadata.namespace
- name: MY_POD_IP
  valueFrom:
    fieldRef:
      fieldPath: status.podIP
```

Now, `echo $MY_POD_IP` will provide you pod IP inside container. Hope this helps.